# Commuting normal operators have common eigenbasis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, mathematics, linear-algebra

One often finds in quantum mechanics textbooks (for physicists) a "proof" that self-adjoint and commuting operators $A,B$ have a common eigenbasis. However, in the standard proof of Bloch's theorem (see e.g. Ballentine Chapter 5.3) one uses that commuting *normal* operators have a joint eigenbasis. How does one show this? I'm not readily able to see how it generalizes to arbitrary normal operators -- even Ballentine just quotes the theorem he proved for self-adjoint operators rather than showing that it holds for arbitrary commuting normal operators too.

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem for normal operators (say, for the sake of simplicity, in finite dimensions)? IIRC, from that it is basically the same procedure as in the hermitian case (which indeed is a special case of normal operators).

Comment: To be clear (and maybe I am not understanding you), I am not asking if normal operators can be diagonalized (that I know) but rather whether or why two (or more) commuting normal operators have a joint eigenbasis. @TobiasFünke

Comment: Yes, I understand. There might be different proofs for the fact that two commuting hermitian operators have a common eigenbasis, but you might check the proof of this in the book, for example, and see whether or not it makes use of the fact that the operators are hermitian in particular, or only uses diagonalizability.

Comment: Ah, my bad for misunderstanding you. I did reread Ballentine's proof and it made use of the fact that self-adjoint operators have orthogonal eigenspaces. @TobiasFünke

Comment: I'm not quite sure I see, but for the moment some more research seems to say that the statement is indeed true. @TobiasFünke

Comment: If all Ballentine uses is that the operator admits an orthonormal basis, then this works for normal operators as well (in finite dimensions; I'm not sure about infinite dimensions), because in finite dimensions, an operator is normal if and only if it admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: @march I've never seen that statement. Up to you if you want to supply an answer for me to check off or not!

Comment: @TobiasFünke I said they were diagonalizable, but does that imply that their eigenspaces are orthonormal (I ask as a question genuinely)?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure anymore about my previous statement, one should check tho (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392983/what-does-it-mean-for-a-matrix-to-be-orthogonally-diagonalizable)) and  I thus removed the comment. Anyway: An operator is hermitian if and only if it is normal with real eigenvalues. Now go through the proof of Ballentine and check whether or not it makes use of the fact that the eigenvalues are real. If not, the result should hold for any normal operator.

Answer (score 0):

In finite dimensions, an operator is normal if and only if it is unitarily diagonalizable, i.e., if it admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. Since the proof that two commuting operators share an eigenbasis only uses the fact that that the basis is *orthogonal*, we can conclude that two commuting normal operators necessarily share an eigenbasis.